# Boost.Tokenizer how to not remove separators from tokens

Tags: c++, boost

Is there posibility not to remove chars, which are char_separators<> for boost::tokenizer<>?

If yes, how to do it?

I want to tokenize string "[a]str1[/a][b]str2[/b]" into:

[a], str1, [/a], [b], str2, [/b]

My delimiters are chars: "<" and ">", by default boost remove them.

Comment: could you be more specific as to what exactly you're asking -- remove chars from where? why? what are you trying to achieve? some code too please

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As per the [documentation](http://www.boost.org/doc/libs/1_55_0/libs/tokenizer/char_separator.htm), the constructor of `char_separator` has 3 parameters: `const Char* dropped_delims`, `const Char* kept_delims`, `empty_token_policy empty_tokens`.

Just pass your separator characters into `kept_delims` instead of `dropped_delims` (i.e. as the second argument). They will be returned as separate tokens then.